# How to automatically match new column name with predefined alias in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, alias, difflib

I am receiving csv files on a regular basis, that I then process using pandas.
Alas, the columns in these files are inconsistent from one delivery to the next. For instance, a column once labeled `largo_diseno` may be renamed `Largo Diseño (mt)` the next day and then `Largo Diseño` the following one.

Of course, I could manually rename the input columns or specify a list of aliases for each parameter (`largo-diseno`, `largodiseno`, etc...), possibly preprocessing input strings using `lower` to reduce the number of possibilities. **But is there a more robust way to match new column names with existing aliases?**

The first solution that comes to my mind is to rely on `difflib`, *e.g.*:

```
import difflib
word = 'Largo Diseño (mt)'
aliases = ['largo_diseno', 'easting', 'northing']
difflib.get_close_matches(word, aliases, n=1, cutoff=0.3)
```

The snippet above returns `largo_diseno` as the best possible match, which is great. My only issue here is that I do not know how to adjust the `cutoff` to ensure a single output. Also, I noticed that the above solution fails when dealing with one letter keywords (e.g. `x`, `y` and `z`):

```
import difflib
word = 'X'
asliases = ['x', 'y', 'z']
difflib.get_close_matches(word, aliases, n=1, cutoff=0.3)
```

Is there a better solution to achieve this, possibly native to Pandas?

Comment: Have you tried https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/.

Comment: My preference would be to normalize all incoming columns in the same way. For example: always lower case, replace whitespace with underscore, use unidecode (for example) to remove accents (i.e. ñ -> n), et.c. and then do an exact lookup, and if it fails add more rules to the normalization process (i.e. always remove everything within a parenthesis) if it makes sense and is not likely to produce false positives, and if not, manually add the new column as a synonym of the correct column.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @NguyễnVũTrungHiếu: no, I did not know about fuzzywuzzy. I will check it out. user3271881: thanks for suggesting the unidecode trick: I am sure that it will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @roganjosh. This is what I got from copying and pasting a snippet from the Internet without reading it in detail... I undeleted my question: if you turn your comment into an answer, I will gladly accept it.